# How to query in AWS athena connected through S3 using lambda functions in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-athena

I have my .csv files saved in the S3 Bucket. I am able to query the data of S3 using AWS Athena. Is there any way we can connect the lambda function to athena and query the data from lambda function. please help

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes! You can use boto3 to interact with Athena.

Particularly, you're going to probably want the start_query_execution method.

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution

Comment: Exactly this :p

Comment: Hi pollard I tried using the syntax given by them but i am unable to specify the parameters  to insert in the syntax. If possible can you please give me a small tutorial. It will help me alot. Actually the documentation provided by boto3 is not enough. Any example will work .
Thanks and Regards
Vipendra

Answer (score 40):

Like Chris Pollard said, you can use boto3 to query Athena from a Lambda function.

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/athena.html

To initialize the Athena client:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('athena')
```

You will then execute your query:

```
queryStart = client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString = 'SELECT * FROM myTable',
    QueryExecutionContext = {
        'Database': 'myDatabase'
    }, 
    ResultConfiguration = { 'OutputLocation': 's3://your-bucket/key'}
)
```

If you want to retrieve the results within Lambda (possibly using a second function, due to time constraints - see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html#limits-list) - also note that you pay per 100ms running time), you would use `get_query_execution` to determine the status of the query:

```py
queryExecution = client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=queryStart['QueryExecutionId'])
```

You will need to parse the returned object for the value of the `QueryExecution.Status.State` field. Continue updating the object using `get_query_execution()` until the result is `Succeeded`.

*Note: Please don't call `get_query_execution()` in a continuous loop. Rather, use an [exponential backoff algorithm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html) to prevent being throttled by that API. You should use this approach for all API calls.*

Then you can use `get_query_results()` to retrieve the results for processing:

```py
results = client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId=queryStart['QueryExecutionId'])
```

Comment: Hi i got one error. It says 
"errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nMissing required parameter in input: \"ResultConfiguration\""

Comment: Read the documentation for the method call.
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution

Comment: The command client.get_query_execution(queryStart.QueryExecutionId) gives error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'QueryExecutionId'. I had to change to client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=queryStart['QueryExecutionId'])

Answer (score 7):

The simplest is to use [awscrawler](https://pypi.org/project/awswrangler/) and its [custom layer for aws lambda](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html)

```py
import awswrangler as wr
sql = "select * from my_table"
df = wr.athena.read_sql_query(
    sql=sql, database="my_table", ctas_approach=True
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use boto3 client to query Athena tables.

You can read more about it here: [Simple way to query Amazon Athena in python with boto3](https://www.ilkkapeltola.fi/2018/04/simple-way-to-query-amazon-athena-in.html)